# shinydashboard Sidebar Menu Overflow

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there any way to fit some sort of text on `shinydashboard` with word wrap? The default behaviour seems to be for it to spill over into the body area.

I would like to avoid modifying css directly however if there is a workaround which involves modifying CSS as part of the server / ui code itself then I'm open to that.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(
      title = "Sidebar spill"

   ),
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
         menuItem(text = "sfsdf sfaosh oas fwue wi aseiu wehw wuer woeur owuer  ")
         )
      ),
   dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(

      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something that can be solved by setting your CSS. Something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: I've tried it and some other CSS tricks too but have been unable to get a solution. The best I've managed are scrollbars with  `overflow`.

Comment: if you want to modify it as part of the code, you can always use `tags$head(tags$style(PUTCSSCODEHERE))`. You can always paste together your css programmatically if you're willing to return those tags from a `renderUI`

Comment: Could you show a working example please?

Answer (score 4):

The file "AdminLTE.min.css" (this version of it anyway in this version of Shinydashboard) specifies "white-space: nowrap !important" for the "sidebar-menu" class as well as "li" elements with class "header" that are direct descendents of elements with the "sidebar-menu" class. I saw that the "li" elements in the sidebar menu of my Shinydashboard application do not have the "header" class, so I overrode "white-space: nowrap !important" (that was being applied because the "ul" element containing the menu is of class "sidebar-menu") by adding the following CSS to a custom CSS file:

```
.sidebar-menu > li {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this

```
...
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      tags$div(class="header", checked=NA,
               tags$p("sfsdf sfaosh oas fwue", tags$br(), "wi aseiu wehw wuer woeur owuer")
      )
    )
  ),
...
```

Comment: This would work for this isolated case. It might not work on different displays or with different items.

Comment: maybe you should add another example (or as you say a different display) to your question :)

Comment: Any time I change the text, I will need to recalculate the placement of `tags$br()`. That's why it won't work on different items.